# boost::variant members subset of another boost::variant

Tags: c++, boost, c++98

I'm working with a rather awkward c interface for storing collections. The class `LowLevelStorer` represents the wrapper I have written to for this interface. The `Storer` class is a high level class which concerns itself with `Data`. It does caching and bundles data into more complex data types known only to the `LowLevelStorer`. The rest of my code cencerns itself only with `Data` and has no knowledge of `LowLevelData`.

In the example code below, I wish for the members in the `Data` variant to be included in the `LowLevelData` variant. Is there a way to specify this other that how I have done it?

What I really don't understand is why the code below compiles and indeed, why it actually works correctly. That is, `void operator()(const SimplePath&, const Data& data) const` takes a Data reference but seems to be correctly converting it to a LowLevelData object when calling `void operator()(const LowLevelData& data) const`. How can this be?

Are there a lot of copies taking place here behind the scenes with regard to my data objects?

```
#include "boost/variant.hpp"
#include "boost/variant/apply_visitor.hpp"
#include <vector>

class Complex{};
typedef boost::variant< std::vector<Complex>, std::vector<int>, std::vector<std::string> > LowLevelData;

class LowLevelStorer
{
public:
    LowLevelStorer(): _storeVisitor(StoreVisitor()){}

    void operator()(const LowLevelData& data) const 
    {
        boost::apply_visitor(_storeVisitor, data);
    }

private:
    class StoreVisitor: public boost::static_visitor<>
    {
    public:
        void operator()(const std::vector<Complex>&) const {}

        void operator()(const std::vector<int>& i) const {}

        void operator()(const std::vector<std::string>&) const {}
    };

    StoreVisitor _storeVisitor;
};


struct SimplePath{};
struct BundlePath{};
typedef boost::variant< SimplePath, BundlePath > Path;

typedef boost::variant< std::vector<std::string>, std::vector<int> > Data;

class Storer
{
public:
    Storer(const LowLevelStorer& lowLevelStorer): _converter(Converter(lowLevelStorer)){}

    void operator()(const Path& path, const Data& data) const 
    {
        boost::apply_visitor(_converter, path, data);
    }

private:
    class Converter: public boost::static_visitor<>
    {
    public:
        Converter(const LowLevelStorer& lowLevelStorer): _lowLevelStorer(lowLevelStorer){}

        void operator()(const SimplePath&, const Data& data) const {
            _lowLevelStorer(data);
        }

        void operator()(const BundlePath&, const Data& data) const {
            _lowLevelStorer(std::vector<Complex>());
        }
    private:
        const LowLevelStorer _lowLevelStorer;
    };

    const Converter _converter;
};

int main()
{
    Storer storer((LowLevelStorer()));
    std::vector<int> v;
    v.push_back(13);
    storer(Path(SimplePath()),v);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why it takes one variant when you've supplied the parameter as the other I suspect is because both of your variants have all types in common, which makes your variants convertible to each other.

I think it would be perfectly fine to just use one variant with all three types and skip the other one entirely, seeing the second is merely a subset of types of the first.

Comment: This is pretty much it- a Data is guaranteed to hold an object which would fit in a LowLevelData.

Comment: @Tony The Lion I still need two variants, since the Data variant does not contain a std::vector<Complex>. This member is used by the low level interface but I want it hidden from the high level interface.

Comment: @Baz then why not have a variant with the other two types, and pass the `Complex` vector as a seperate argument where needed?

Comment: @Tony The Lion Of course, thanks for pointing out the obvious!